# C++- Saxon c/c++ How to import saxon to project in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, c, xml-parsing, saxon

I downloaded saxon he c/c++ and install it and now please some one show me how to use it in project in Visual?
I search in Google but seem like nothing work.
Nice to have example and step to include saxon.
My project need export file which have schema plmxml to xml schema file.
In window btw.
Thanks

Comment: Did you search for it?   How about  http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml

Comment: Yes i read this but no really help. They just show code only but nó show how to use that lib.

Comment: Saxon HE supports XSLT 3, XPath 3 and XQuery 3. In what way do you think it can help you to "export file which have schema plmxml to xml schema file"? What is a plmxml file? How does it relate to Saxon? Do you have some XSLT or XQuery to transform such plmxml files to schema files?

Comment: So what if i want to export xml to hmtl with xsl schema how do i do in visual

Comment: Building Saxon/C in Visual Studio is not well supported. In the past I have managed to get it to build in Visual studio, but there are some differences with the MSVC compiler vs GCC. Feel free to try it yourself. When you create simple  Visual studio C/C++ project you can use our sample code testXSLT-Win.cpp file (in the samples/cpp directory) to get started. You will probably come across various compile errors. 

I will revisit building under Windows for the next release of Saxon/C.

Comment: @ond1 hi i tried but i doesnt work, is there any way to automation build xml by saxon ( exapl create a bat and call saxon by c++) i download gcc and g++ but don know how to run example

Comment: @hà-yen I will look into this for the next release.